# Reorder DOM nodes without removing / appending them

Tags: javascript, html, dom

My "component" receives an object in this form:

```
{ p0: 3, p1: 2, p4: 6, p9: 3 }
```

Object can have a subset of properties p0 .. p9. My component should create Input type=range for each property and allow user to edit any property of current object. When property is edited, new (edited) object is propagated to parent and parent sets it back to all components in program (including my component).

My current component has 10 hidden inputs. In SetObject, I remove all displayed inputs (removeChild) and then append (appendChild) only those, that are present in received object.

The problem is, that while dragging input with a mouse, property is changed, object is propagated up and down, current input is removed and appended again, and loses focus (no visual change, but can not be dragged any further).

What is a nice way to solve it? I would like to keep inputs that are in both previous and new object (to keep focus on them), but I also want them to be ordered correctly.

Comment: The code appending is strongly recommended. It is even not clear what do you mean by "components" and why do you need to remove children at all.

Answer (score 0):

It is not obvious without your code but why do you remove and then append elements? Maybe it's better to leave your inputs as they are and just set to its proper `value`?

Comment: I am removing and appending nodes, because I can receive different objects ... e.g. {p0:3, p4:2}, and later {p2:6,p3:4}. Only properties from last received objects should be editable.

Comment: So what will happen if user is editing the p5's range and then new object comes with no p5? Any way my recommendation still the same: do not remove nodes if it possible. If it's not - you can try to set focus manually on that element which triggered the change. But I doubt that it is possible to do seamlessly for user.

Comment: Maybe I can reformulate my problem: You receive an array of strings ["p0", "p3", "p7"] and you should fill container with nodes, containing "p0", "p3", "p7" in correct order. You should keep the node containing "pX", if it was presen in previous sequence.  But maybe my problem is too specific and not appropriate for SO.